# How to find out an IP is pointed to gmail or pointed to google?

Tags: networking, ip

I am trying to find some webmail servers via testing their IPs.
When I type an IP into browser, it shows goole's searching engine.  However, even though it belongs to gmail, when I type it into the browser, the browser will be directed to google's searching engine. Is there anyway can help me to find out whether a specific IP belongs to google's searching engine or gmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, now I know how  find out an IP is pointed to gmail or pointed to google.Two ways, the first way is to look into the data's head of the flow, it is not convenient, but it is the most precise way. The second way is use firefox. I type "https://server'ip" into firefox, open it, firefox will shows:"

`173.194.33.182 uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: mail.google.com, inbox.google.com` " I only find chrome and firefox can do this so far, but chrome browser only shows me where the certification of this IP comes from, not as precise as firefox.